# How to copy column from last column N number of times?

Tags: vba, excel

I currently have the following code, which was made by a lovely member here

```
Sub YearsNumberReduction()
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim DelCnt As Integer
DelCnt = Sheets("Panel").Range("E19").Value
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Current")
    LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    If LastCol >= DelCnt Then
        .Range(.Cells(1, LastCol - DelCnt + 1), .Cells(1, LastCol)).EntireColumn.Delete
    End If
End With
```

This code takes the last column, and deletes the column by the number of times specified in E19. How can I change the code, so instead of deleting a specified number of times from the last row, we can add columns instead? Essentially reversing the role of that VBA Macro.

I also have another question. In my Excel solution, I constantly add the number of years and decrease them (those years are business years and each year carries a profit, calculated by revenue-costs). On the main worksheet, I have 10 years. That is the default number of years. However, this does not change when I add or decrease years based on the function I mentioned. The profit for the 10 years is calculated by =SUM(B29:B39). How can I make the range change (e.g if I add one more year, Year 11 will be added and =SUM(B29:40) in the main spreadsheet which gives a profit overview?

Current adding of columns

```
Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L1:L15").AutoFill Destination:=Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("L1").Resize(15, Worksheets("Panel").Range("E17") + 1), Type:=xlFillDefault
```

However, this adds from a fixed column, rather than the last. So I extend columns by 5, it will add 5, but if I extend it by 5 again, it wont extend since it has a fixed point. So I need it to change based on the last column.

EDIT

```
Year 1  Year 2  Year 3  Year 3  Year 3
Sales   100 115 132 132 152
Costs   30  32  33  33  35
Profit  70  84  99  99  99
```

Year 3 stays the same, and costs do not update (=C3*1.05) it should rise by 5%

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This is finding the last column so there will presumably be available columns after so what is the purpose of adding more columns? You want to duplicate the last column n times?

Comment: Where is this function you mention? You could increase your SUM with a lastRow calculation e.g. "B29:B" & lastRow

Comment: Thanks for replying! The function needs to add a number of columns specified by the user, starting from the last. I would need the complete reverse of the code I mentioned, where I can select the number of columns to add from another worksheet, starting from the last, and if I want to add more columns, it will continue adding from the last, never from a pre-specified column

Comment: Yes, I am copying the last column, but it can be any column.

Comment: Edited and added what I have so far

Comment: Not sure what you are expecting if you simply want to copy the last column the number of times specified in Range E19 then   .Range(.Cells(1, LastCol + 1), .Cells(1, LastCol + DelCnt)).EntireColumn = .Cells(1, LastCol).EntireColumn.Value

Comment: @QHarr Thanks, that seems to do the job although only the values are being copied rather than the formulas, as well as the first row within the column is year and that stays fixed too. Would it be possible for the function to do the exact same role, but copy formulas rather than concrete values?

Comment: That doesn't seem to work, the years dont change and the formula applies not from the previous column, but from the one before that. Is there anything else I could try?

Comment: Done @QHarr  Hope that helps (That is after I ran the Macro, which extends years by 2)

Comment: Is Year 1 etc text? Or is it numeric e.g. 2017 And the formula is supposed to be in which row looking at which row?

Comment: Its text, but when I autofill it goes 2,3,4 etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following. Assumes you can use column A to find the last used row:

```
Sub YearsNumberReduction()

    Dim LastCol As Long
    Dim DelCnt As Integer
    DelCnt = Sheets("Panel").Range("E19").Value
    Dim copyCol As Range
    Dim DestRange As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Current")

        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        LastCol = .Cells(1, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

        Set copyCol = .Range(.Cells(1, LastCol), .Cells(lastRow, LastCol))

        Set DestRange = .Range(.Cells(1, LastCol), .Cells(lastRow, LastCol + DelCnt))

        copyCol.AutoFill Destination:= DestRange, Type:=xlFillDefault

    End With


End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks! I added a picture on the end, and it seems to drag the formula not from the previous cell, but from the one before the previous, hence the figures wont carry on correctly, I assume

Comment: Code above takes from prior column

Comment: Thanks, however, the formula for profit, is completely re-arranged, ive attached the image to see

Comment: so K3 should be J3*1.05 , L3 should be K3*1.05 etc? Is it just that row that is a problem?

Comment: Every column, profit is not worked out for the current year. The columns should be autofilled, rather than anything else, based from the last column, N number of times, I think that would get the solution. @QHarr

Comment: Profit formula: F2-F3 is supposed to be G2-G3?

Comment: Making sure cell A1 has text in it such as "Header" , then with my code and using your first 3 years i get year 4 , sales 133, Costs 35.28 and profits 97.72 this is correct for using autofill. I think we are missing something else here.

Comment: Does anyone else have a solution, which performs the reverse of the formula I mentioned?

Comment: What are your expected values for year 4?